# You cannot do something to yourself; how are you going to advise me?

Tags: phrase-request

Imagine someone who is unable to do his own affairs is trying to advise you in your problems which are exactly the same as what they have no idea how to deal with in their own life. Is there a proverb in modern AmE to ask / tell the adviser guy: "mind your own business. Because if you could do something, you have already done for yourself"?

I've found two proverbs, which although I'me sure they can be indicative in AmE, but they cannot be considered natural:

> **a)** Physician, heal yourself.
>
> **b)** He tells me my may, but doesn’t know his own.

Am I right? If yes, then please let me know how an American would say the same thing?

Comment: The first proverb reads ["Physician, heal thyself](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Physician,+heal+thyself)". And where did you find the second one? The link please!

Comment: I don;t remember exactly, but I guess I read it once somewhere. It was certainly a translation page @Rompey.

Answer (score 3):

There are probably a number of proverbs which can be used.  Using proverbs etc. in this way can sound a bit abrupt, but if you have a very strong reason for saying them it can be justified.

2 examples of proverbs I can think of right now are...

1. People in glass houses shouldn't throw stones
2. Put your own house in order first

You could also opt to ask a question as a retort by saying

> How can you advise me when you can't sort your own problems out?